# How to access user control's image from parent page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I have a user control that upload image and show it to users. After upload image in parent page I want to save the image URL to database but I can't. This is my code that I used but the image is null.

```
Image img = new Image();  
img = this.Uploade1.FindControl("Image1") as Image;
```

---

My code:  My User Control:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<contenttemplate>
            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                    <td rowspan="3">
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="100" ImageAlign="Middle" Width="100" />
                        <br />
                        <asp:Label ID="StatusLabel" runat="server" Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">

                        <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUploadControl" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style2">

                        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" OnClick="ButtonUpload_Click" Text="بارگذاری" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
        </contenttempl
```

```
protected void ButtonUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Path to store uploaded files on server - make sure your paths are unique
        string Id = Request.QueryString["id"];
        //string thumbPath = "../upFiles/_thumb_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";
        //string filePath = thumbPath.Replace("_thumb_", "");
        string filePath = "../upFiles/" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".jpg";

        try
        {
            // Check that there is a file
            if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
            {
                if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentType == "image/jpeg")
                {
                    if (FileUploadControl.PostedFile.ContentLength  0) && (System.IO.Path.GetExtension(myFile.FileName).ToLower() == ".jpg"))
                        {
                            // Read file into a data stream
                            byte[] myData = new Byte[nFileLen];
                            myFile.InputStream.Read(myData, 0, nFileLen);
                            myFile.InputStream.Dispose();

                            // Save the stream to disk as temporary file. 
                            // make sure the path is unique!
                            System.IO.FileStream newFile
                                    = new System.IO.FileStream(Server.MapPath(filePath.Remove(0,3)),
                                                    System.IO.FileMode.Create);
                            newFile.Write(myData, 0, myData.Length);


                            newFile.Close();


                            System.IO.File.Delete(Server.MapPath(filePath.Remove(0, 3) +"_temp.jpg"));

                            //. new cpode
                            Image1.ImageUrl = filePath.Remove(0, 3);
                        }
                    }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            StatusLabel.Text =  ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share more code

Comment: these are my user control code and parent page is just two lines code that i wrote in top of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Session** to save image url, then in child page retrive that and save to database.

first page:

```
Session["url"] = imageUrl;
```

second page:

```
string url = (string)Session["url"] ;
//save to database
```